# Are C standard library functions thread-safe in absence of C11 threads?

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi, c11

I am writing a multi-threaded program on Windows. Since there is no windows implementation of C that I know of to support C11 threads, my best bet is to use the native WinAPI multi-threading. But there is a catch. Some functions in the C library, such as `malloc` or I/O functions are demanded to be thread-safe by the C11 standard. But are they required to be thread-safe even if `__STDC_NO_THREADS__` is defined? It seems pointless for them to be thread-safe if no thread facilities exist in the C implementation, but it would truly help since I really don't want to have to wrap all I/O functions in mutexes.

Comment: I cannot quite seem to reconcile the contradiction between `I am writing a multi-threaded program` and `no thread facilities exist in the implementation`.

Comment: @goodvibration I meant to say C implementation. As I said in the beginning, I am using native Win32 threads.

Comment: Thread-safe was a concept before C11.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Obviously it was, but some C functions are demanded to be thread-safe starting with C11 because it introduced threads. My implementation does not support them (they are optional in the standard), and I am asking if the functions (`malloc()`, `printf()` etc are still thread-safe)

Comment: You will have to check documentation on MSDN about that, but mostly yes, at least if you are linking against multi-threaded runtime.

Comment: @StaceyGirl Ok, thank you for the information!

Comment: Your title says, "...C functions," but did you mean, C _standard library_ functions? If so, you might edit the title to make that clear. Also, consider adding the [tag:winapi] tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you compile and link against the Microsoft multithread runtime library then functions like malloc() will be thread safe.

This is not a language guarantee but it is guaranteed by the platform.

Oh, and [read MSDN carefully](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/beginthread-beginthreadex?view=vs-2019). Using threads in C or C++ you need to use `_beginthread()` or `_beginthreadex()`, not the Win32 CreateThread

And more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/parallel/multithreading-with-c-and-win32?view=vs-2019

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea that I had to use `_beginthread()` instead of `CreateThread()`!

Comment: "Using threads in C or C++ you need to use beginthread" This is a very old old myth. Simply don't call the CRT from your threads and you can use CreateThread just fine. I think the origin of this myth was a bug in Visual Studio and/or the Microsoft CRT specifically, not in the actual Win API. If I remember correctly, it was related to MFC.

Comment: @lun You remember wrong. Nothing to do with MFC. And the *"very old old myth"* you are referring to was a bug in Microsoft's CRT implementation that caused it to leak memory, if a thread using the CRT wasn't created using `_beginthread`. That bug is fixed. The [documented issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createthread#remarks), however, is still there.

Comment: @Lundin If the documentation says to use `_beginthread()`, then you should use it. And if the GCC documentation says to use `-pthread` instead of `-lpthread` then you should do that too. If someone bothered to document it, assume they had a good reason.

Comment: @IInspectable That's what I wrote: "Simply don't call the CRT from your threads and you can use CreateThread just fine."

Comment: @lun Why create all that noise, though? Clearly, the OP *is* using the CRT, like practically any non-trivial application. Now what you're really saying is much, much more dangerous: You are calling the documentation wrong, since you never observed any issues, because you worked around their precondition. That's negligent, criminally at that.

Answer (score 0):

No, standard library functions are not guaranteed to be thread-safe, regardless of thread library used. C11 7.1.4/4 explicitly states:

> The functions in the standard library are not guaranteed to be reentrant and may modify objects with static or thread storage duration.

A particular standard library implementation or a library standard extension may provide thread-safe functions, on case by case basis.

Comment: Have your read 7.1.4/5? `malloc()`, for example, does not modify static or thread storage, so it is thread-safe.

Comment: @DarkAtom Specific exceptions in the standard libs can be made. The relevant part for malloc specifically is 7.22.3/2 "For purposes of determining the existence of a data race, memory allocation functions behave as though they accessed only memory locations accessible through their arguments and not other static duration storage. These functions may, however, visibly modify the storage that they allocate or deallocate."  But generally, such exceptions are not made for standard lib functions.

Comment: You clearly didn't read the question entirely. I specifically mentioned `malloc()` and friends (which are guaranteed to be thread-safe by 7.22.3) and I/O functions (which are guaranteed to be thread-safe by 7.21.2/7 and 7.21.2/8). Obviously I was not refering to functions like `strtok()` (which cannot be thread-safe because they have static storage).

Comment: @DarkAtom I read the question just fine, let me quote it for you: "Are C standard library functions thread-safe in absence of C11 threads?"

Comment: "Some functions in the C library, such as malloc or I/O functions are demanded to be thread-safe", "But are they required to be thread-safe even if `__STDC_NO_THREADS__` is defined?". I cannot put all details in the title of the question, you have to read the whole topic.

Answer (score 0):

Even in C11, guarantees of atomicity or thread safety within the Standard are only meaningful with regard to signals or threads that are created by Standard-defined means.  If a thread is created via some means not specified by the Standard, anything that thread might do, including its possible interactions with other threads, would be outside the jurisdiction of the Standard.

Quality implementations intended for low-level programming on systems where it's possible to create threads or trigger asynchronous signals will generally allow programs to interact with such things in ways beyond those required by the Standard, since the Standard would provide for essentially nothing.

Answer (score -1):

The most obvious and avoidable are those functions that use and often return a subroutine static data element, which of course is on the heap even though the name context is local.  They are rare, but asctime() and some of its friends come to mind.  https://linux.die.net/man/3/asctime  The man page says obsolete, use strftime().  However, any function that exhibits 'state' probably has a static inside!  For instance, strtok(): https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok  I never liked it, preferring to parse my strings by hand and not modify the input, using pointer derived lengths.  So beware.  A good C programmer could write most of these library routines, and so can imagine where subroutine static (or file static global or global) are used to give 'state'.

BTW, by strict definition, functions should have no state, but subroutines can!  In C++, JAVA, etc. methods keep their state in their object or class, and for thread support can include a mutex at either or both levels, or you can make JAVA methods 'synchronized'!

Comment: How does this answer my question? `asctime()` and `strtok()` are not required to be thread-safe by the Standard (and definitely aren't). I was asking about the functions that are required to be thread-safe. Also, why are you linking Linux man pages when I am using Windows?

Comment: C and man pages do not care about the OS, as most is pretty portable.  Functions are either thread safe, or not.  They might be labeled as such in some references.  If you write them, then the word 'required' comes into play.  One way to make them thread safe is to avoid globals and static, or to protect common resources with a mutex.  Another path to thread safe is monotonically ascending, as concurrent threads might see old values (stale cache) that do not enable problems.  I wrote a ring buffer with unsigned long in and out counters.